# How do I modify this code to paste in the row under last row with data?

Tags: excel, vba

I've put this code together and it works perfectly except it pastes the copied cells into the last row that it finds data in and I need it to paste it in the row below this.

How do I move the position it pastes to down one row?

```
Sub SelectActualUsedRange()

 Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

 Sheets("Set Up Current Month").Select

 Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
  Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

 Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
  Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

 Range(FirstCell, LastCell).Select
 Selection.Copy

 Sheets("Pasted Report").Select

 If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
   Set FirstCell = Range("A1")
 Else
    Set FirstCell = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
 End If

 Set LastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

 LastCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I changes the bottom part of the code to -

```
Set LastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

LastCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub